# How to set variables in a js file and include it to a userscript

Tags: javascript, variables, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

i wanna set variables in a js file called vars.js

Uploaded vars.js to my ftp server and tried to include it into my userscript by using;

```
//@require http://serverip/vars.js
```

When I wanna access a variable, function etc. from vars.js

vars.js:

```
var a = function(b){
 alert(b);
 }
```

////
userscript;

```
...
//@require http://serverip/vars.js
a("something to alert here");
```

Basically doesn't work and gives an error:

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'New userscript' failed! a is not a function
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you using CommonJS (Node.js)?

Comment: No regular js, the one you use in html in between <script> tags. I am actually using tampermonkey to run a simple script. I'll create many of scripts for each link i wanna run the script on and don't really wanna keep adding variables over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the import command instead, like:

```
// ES6 syntax
import * as A from './A.js';
const foo = A.foo;
const baz = A.baz;
```

Comment: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'